# Multiple Resources & Reporting

Tags: ms-project, project-planning, ms-project-server-2013

I have a question about creating a custom report in Project 2013. We currently have projects going on that have 3 or 4 project plans with all interconnected dependencies on each other. When I bring all of the plans together and try to run a resource report, I run into an issue. Many of our tasks have 2 or more resources connected to them and when I group by resource, it does not break them out. I have tried using the "Resource Usage" view, but need to have all of the project plans open to accomplish creating a nice looking report and even then it is not very nice looking. 
I am looking to create a report that breaks out what each individual resource has assigned to them over the next 2-3 weeks. It is more a report to hand to our business leads to says here is what we need from your teams and here's what they are assigned to. I am looking to break it out like this:
By Resource - listing only one person (not the large group of people if 2+ are assigned to a task), list only the hours that they have allocated to the task, and move on.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Our company has had to write proprietary code (VBA & VB.Net) in Access, Excel, and Project to create these kinds of reports. I'd be in big trouble if I posted any of it! I, personally, am not aware of an easier way, but maybe there is.

Answer (score 0):

The non code or VBA solution is to use a resource pool instead of having separate lists of resources in each file. Once the resources are pooled (shared) with a single file, all resource reporting can be done against that file. There are a lot of caveats that go along with doing it this way though.